# Can we define partial group actions on (finite) sets via generators and relators?

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G = \langle Y | R \rangle$ be a finitely presented group. A *partial group action* on a set $X$ is a *premorphism* into the inverse semigroup
$$
\mathcal I (X) = \{ f: A \to B : A, B \subseteq X, f\text{ is bijective}\}. 
$$
I.e. $\mathcal I(X)$ is the set of partial bijections on $X$. The semigroup operation on $\mathcal I(X)$ is just function composition, restricted to the relevant domain. There is a natural partial order on $\mathcal I(X)$, given by inclusion. Particularly, $f \leq g$ if and only if $f$ is a restriction of $g$.

A *premorphism* $\theta : G \to \mathcal I(X)$ is a map satisfying the following axioms:

1. $\theta(g^{-1}) = \theta(g)^{-1}$ for every $g \in G$,
2. $\theta(g) \theta(h) \leq \theta(gh)$, for every $g,h \in G$,
3. $\theta(1) = \mathrm{id}_X$.

Classically, if we define a map $\phi : Y \to H$ for some group $H$, we can check if this extends to a homomorphism (and thus a group action) by checking if relators map to the identity under the universal free extension $F(Y) \to H$.

I am interested in extending this classical idea to partial group actions. In particular, given a (finite) set $X$, and a map $\theta : Y \to \mathcal I(X)$, is it possible to check in a similar way whether $\theta$ extends to a premorphism $\hat \theta : G \to \mathcal I(X)$?

If $G = F(Y)$ then this question is answered in the positive by defining
$$
\hat \theta (y_1^{\epsilon_1} \ldots y_n^{\epsilon_n}) := \theta (y_1)^{\epsilon_1} \ldots \theta(y_n)^{\epsilon_n}
$$
for freely reduced $y_1^{\epsilon_1} \ldots y_n^{\epsilon_n}$.

I'm working on a problem where the connectivity of a certain graph is equivalent to the (non-)existence of a certain type of partial group action. The overall goal is to decide if this graph is connected, and thus is reduced to deciding if this partial action exists.

I'm relatively new to the theory of semigroups and partial group actions, so apologies if this problem is ill-posed or trivial. Let me know if anything can be clarified in the above. Any guidance is appreciated!

**Edit:**

It is has been helpfully pointed out in the comments that partial actions need not be determined by the action of a generating set. It makes sense to therefore consider the following restriction of the problem.

We say that a partial action $\theta : G \to \mathcal I(X)$ *is generated by $Y$* if for all $g \in G$, $q, q' \in X$, we have that $\theta(g)(q) = q'$ if and only if there exists $y_1, \ldots , y_n \in Y^{\pm 1}$ such that $g = y_1 \ldots y_n$, and
$$
\theta(y_1)\ldots \theta(y_n)(q) = q'.
$$
One can then rephrase the question in this setting as follows:

> Given a map $\theta : Y \to \mathcal I(X)$, can we decide if there exists a partial action $\hat \theta : G \to \mathcal I (X)$ which extends $\theta$, and is generated by $Y$?

Below are my main references for this topic.

**References**

1. Kellendonk, J., & Lawson, M. V. (2004). Partial actions of groups. International Journal of Algebra and Computation, 14(01), 87-114.
2. Exel, R. (1998). Partial actions of groups and actions of inverse semigroups. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 126(12), 3481-3494.

Comment: Partial actions need not be determined by how they behave in generators.  Free group actions are more general than what you give

Comment: Your methods works for the free group because the free inverse monoid is an F-inverse monoid with the free group as its maximal group image. In general it is not clear to me when a Y-generated group can be the maximal group image of a Y-generated F-inverse monoid

Comment: Let $u_n$ be the partial action of $\mathbf{Z}$ on the singleton for which every element in $n\mathbf{Z}$ acts as identity of the singleton, and every other element acts with empty domain (concretely this means restriction of the action of $\mathbf{Z}$ on $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ to a singleton of the latter). These are pairwise non-isomorphic partial actions. But as maps from $\mathbf{Z}$ to the inverse semigroup of partial bijections, on the closed $n$-ball, these maps $u_k$ coincide for $k>n$. So there is no finite subset of $\mathbf{Z}$ which "determines" partial actions (unlike actions).

Comment: Thank you both, it makes sense that there is could be no finite subset which determines the partial action. I'd like to propose a restriction on this problem: what if we only consider partial actions $\theta : G \to \mathcal I(X)$ where $\theta(g)(q) = q'$ if and only if one can write $g = y_1,\ldots y_n$ for some $y_i \in Y^{\pm 1}$, and $\theta(y_1)\ldots \theta(y_n) (q) = q'$. Does the action of the generating set determine the whole action now?

Comment: I have edited the question to include this variation.

Comment: It seems to me with your new variation.the partial action is by definition determined by the generating set but it may be difficult to verify if your proposed definition is a partial action

Comment: I doubt I’ll have time to write an answer, but it seems to me that the answer to your edited question is probably that, for a given $G$, the problem is decidable for all partial actions in finite sets if and only if the word problem is solvable in $G$.